# Movie reference at the end of Family Guy Episode 14x08?

Tags: identify-this-movie, reference, family-guy

At the end of Family Guy episode 14x08, Peter wrote some lines on his old computer.

> I never saw much of Joe after that. And while he's been gone for many years, I've never forgetten his face or his laughter.

I know those lines, where do the come from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Though the *dialogue* isn't a direct copy of it, the entire scene is an homage to the end of [Stand By Me](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092005/combined): Peter writing about his old friend on an old computer, his son and and his friend coming in, the song *Stand By Me* playing in the background etc. You can see most of the scene the show referenced here:

Comment: Well, I barely can remember that actual movie, but somehow it was stuck there back in my.head :) God bless we have Family Guy to remember those pieces. :)